# TypeError: mvcRoutes.called is not a function, though I declared it as a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I have been looking at the awesome answers to problems like mine, but still can't find a working alternative, or why my code is failing.
I actually did find someone who posted a problem quite similar to mine, but the answers given to him are not working for me either... and I am too new at js and angular to be able to spot the difference myself.
I was hoping you could give me a hand?

This is my Directives.js

```
    var directives = angular.module("directives", []);

    directives.constant("mvcRoutes", {
        items: {},
        called: function (name) {
            var value = this.items[name];
            if (!value) throw "Could not find route for " + name + " make sure its realy added/defined through script tag!";
            return value;
        }
    });
```

After that, I have my service:

    `directives.service("countryService", ["$http", "mvcRoutes", "$q", function ($http, mvcRoutes, $q) {
        return {
            search: function (text) {
                return $http.post(mvcRoutes.called("country.search"), { text: text});
            }
        };
    }]);`

and lastly, my directive:

    `directives.directive("countrySelector", ["countryService", "$rootScope", function (countryService, $rootScope) {`

```
    var myCtrl;

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<input type="text" id="{{::elementId}}" name="{{::elementId}}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ng-required="" ng-model="country" typeahead-select-on-blur="true" ng-maxlength="50" typeahead-select-on-exact="true" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 800, allowInvalid: true }" uib-typeahead="item.id as item.name for item in getCountries($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" typeahead-template-url="country-template.html" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="1" typeahead-on-select="itemSelected($item, $model, $label, $event)">',
        scope: { elementId: "@elementId", country: "=ngModel", required: "=?ngRequired" },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            myCtrl = ctrl;
        },
        controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            $scope.getCountries = function (text) {
                return countryService.search(text).then(function (response) { return response.data });
            }

            if (!$scope.elementId) $scope.elementId = "country";

            $scope.itemSelected = function ($item, $model, $label) {
                $scope.country = $label;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("countrySelector.selected", { id: $scope.elementId, label: $label });
            }
        }]
    }
}]);
```

I have also my controller defined quite simply, like this:

`[RoutePrefix("{site}/country")]
        public class CountryController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Country
            [Route("search")]
            public ActionResult Search(string text)
            {
                using (var connection = CreateSqlConnection.ToRepairRequestDb())
                {
                    connection.Open();`

```
                return new CountryQuery(text).Execute(connection).AsJsonResult();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CountryQuery : SqlQuery<CountryModel>
    {
        public CountryQuery(string text, int maxRows = 6)
        {
            Parameters = new { text = text.AsSqlWildcard(false), maxRows };
            SqlText = @"                      
                SELECT TOP (@maxRows) CountryID AS ID, CountryName as Name FROM Countries
                WHERE 
                    (@text IS NULL OR CountryID LIKE @text OR CountryName LIKE @text)
                ORDER BY CountryName asc";
        }
    }
```

But when I run it, I get this stack:

```
TypeError: mvcRoutes.called is not a function
    at Object.search (Directives.js:95)
    at Scope.$scope.getCountries (Directives.js:113)
    at Object.fn [as source] (eval at compile (angular.js:13322), <anonymous>:4:317)
    at getMatchesAsync (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:7224)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:7451)
    at NgModelController.$$parseAndValidate (angular.js:25256)
    at NgModelController.$commitViewValue (angular.js:25246)
    at angular.js:25383
    at angular.js:17855
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5507)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a critical mistake... my solution had two directives.js files; and I wrote the declaration on the wrong one, which belongs to a different project.
As soon as I moved it to the correct one, the code worked without problem.